# IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e estou com um probleminha bastante chato. 
É um sistema WEB.

Quando eu busco um cliente ele preenche todos os campos que preciso corretamento porém, quando eu busco outro cliente eu recebo a mensagem de erro abaixo: 
O mais estranho é que os campos estão corretos, string - string, float - float, etc...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: paciente.profissao
```

Procurei várias coisas sobre isto inclusive posts aqui do SOpt e não consegui chegar a uma solução.

Erro mostrado no stracktrace:

```
Set 23, 2014 9:27:02 AM javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot broadcastEvents  
SEVERE: AbortProcessingException thrown when processing event of type 'javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent' during phase 'PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3' for component with ID or Client ID of 'listbox1'  
Set 23, 2014 9:27:02 AM javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot broadcastEvents  
SEVERE: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /medico/prontuario.jsp(816,127) '#{medico$prontuario.listbox1_processValueChange}' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: endereco_paciente.logradouro  
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /medico/prontuario.jsp(816,127) '#{medico$prontuario.listbox1_processValueChange}' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: endereco_paciente.logradouro  
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.event.MethodExprValueChangeListener.processValueChange(MethodExprValueChangeListener.java:73)  
        at javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent.processListener(ValueChangeEvent.java:123)  
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiInput.broadcast(WebuiInput.java:209)  
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:416)  
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor128.invoke(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)  
        at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.components.PartialTraversalViewRootHelper.broadcastEvents(PartialTraversalViewRootHelper.java:500)  
        at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.components.PartialTraversalViewRootHelper.processValidators(PartialTraversalViewRootHelper.java:267)  
        at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.components.PartialTraversalViewRootImpl.processValidators(PartialTraversalViewRootImpl.java:152)  
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:100)  
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)  
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)  
        at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.lifecycle.PartialTraversalLifecycle.execute(PartialTraversalLifecycle.java:94)  
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:267)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)  
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)  
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)  
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)  
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)  
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: endereco_paciente.logradouro  
        at com.sun.data.provider.impl.CachedRowSetDataProvider.getFieldKeyInternal(CachedRowSetDataProvider.java:555)  
        at com.sun.data.provider.impl.CachedRowSetDataProvider.getFieldKey(CachedRowSetDataProvider.java:513)  
        at com.sun.data.provider.impl.AbstractDataProvider.getValue(AbstractDataProvider.java:97)  
        at yagaonline.medico.prontuario.listbox1_processValueChange(prontuario.java:3660)  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)  
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)  
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:172)  
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)  
        at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:68)  
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.event.MethodExprValueChangeListener.processValueChange(MethodExprValueChangeListener.java:71)  
        ... 32 more  

Set 23, 2014 9:27:02 AM javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot broadcastEvents  
SEVERE: AbortProcessingException thrown when processing event of type 'javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent' during phase 'PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3' for component with ID or Client ID of 'listbox1'  
Set 23, 2014 9:27:02 AM javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot broadcastEvents  
SEVERE: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /medico/prontuario.jsp(816,127) '#{medico$prontuario.listbox1_processValueChange}' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: paciente.indicado  
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /medico/prontuario.jsp(816,127) '#{medico$prontuario.listbox1_processValueChange}' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: paciente.indicado  
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.event.MethodExprValueChangeListener.processValueChange(MethodExprValueChangeListener.java:73)  
        at javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent.processListener(ValueChangeEvent.java:123)  
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiInput.broadcast(WebuiInput.java:209)  
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:416)  
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:663)  
        at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.components.PartialTraversalViewRootImpl.processValidators(PartialTraversalViewRootImpl.java:153)  
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:100)  
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)  
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)  
        at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.lifecycle.PartialTraversalLifecycle.execute(PartialTraversalLifecycle.java:94)  
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:267)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)  
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)  
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)  
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)  
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)  
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: paciente.indicado  
        at com.sun.data.provider.impl.CachedRowSetDataProvider.getFieldKeyInternal(CachedRowSetDataProvider.java:555)  
        at com.sun.data.provider.impl.CachedRowSetDataProvider.getFieldKey(CachedRowSetDataProvider.java:513)  
        at com.sun.data.provider.impl.AbstractDataProvider.getValue(AbstractDataProvider.java:97)  
        at yagaonline.medico.prontuario.listbox1_processValueChange(prontuario.java:3658)  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)  
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)  
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:172)  
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)  
        at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:68)  
        at com.sun.webui.jsf.event.MethodExprValueChangeListener.processValueChange(MethodExprValueChangeListener.java:71)  
        ... 28 more  
This message was edited 2 times. Last update was at 23/09/2014 09:29:11
```

Meu código.

```
        try {
        getSessionBean1().getPesqcodpacienteRowSet1().setObject(1, listbox1.getSelected());
        pacienteDataProvider1.refresh();
        //  info("listbox");
        Integer paciente = (Integer) pacienteDataProvider1.getValue("paciente.codigo");
        String nome_paciente = (String) pacienteDataProvider1.getValue("paciente.nome");
        //guarda o código do paciente selecionado na seção
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("cod_paciente", paciente);
          info("paciente" + paciente);
        stmens.setText("teste código ok!");
        nome.setText(nome_paciente);
        tabSet1.setVisible(true);

        //busca e carrega os dados do paciente para todas as tabelas de dados
        getSessionBean1().getAlterapacienteRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        pacienteDataProvider2.refresh();

        getSessionBean1().getPesqendereco_pacienteRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        endereco_pacienteDataProvider.refresh();

        getSessionBean1().getPesqtelefone_pacienteRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        telefone_pacienteDataProvider.refresh();

        getSessionBean1().getAnamneseRowSet().setObject(1, paciente);
        anamneseDataProvider.refresh();

        getSessionBean1().getHistorico_atestadoRowSet().setObject(1, paciente);
        historico_atestadoDataProvider.refresh();

        getSessionBean1().getPesqbioimpedanciometriaRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        pesqbioimpedanciometriaDataProvider1.refresh();


        getSessionBean1().getPesqhistorico_consultaRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        pesqhistorico_consultaDataProvider1.refresh();

        getSessionBean1().getPesqhistorico_dietaRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        pesqhistorico_dietaDataProvider1.refresh();


        getSessionBean1().getPesqhistorico_examesRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        pesqhistorico_examesDataProvider1.refresh();


        getSessionBean1().getFotosantesRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        fotosantesDataProvider1.refresh();

        getSessionBean1().getFotosdepoisRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        fotosdepoisDataProvider1.refresh();

        getSessionBean1().getLista_historico_procedimentosRowSet1().setObject(1, paciente);
        lista_historico_procedimentosDataProvider1.refresh();

        Integer validaresult2 = telefone_pacienteDataProvider.getRowCount();
        //      info("result deo tel "+validaresult2);
        listbox1.setVisible(false);
        if (validaresult2 == 1) {
            addtel.setVisible(true);
            DDD1.setVisible(true);
            tel1.setVisible(true);
            stxddd.setVisible(true);
            stxnum.setVisible(true);
            stxtipo.setVisible(true);
            tipotel1.setVisible(true);
            DDD2.setVisible(true);
            tel2.setVisible(true);
            stxddd1.setVisible(true);
            stxnum1.setVisible(true);
            stxtipo1.setVisible(true);
            tipotel2.setVisible(true);
            btn_tel.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (validaresult2 == 3) {
            addtel.setVisible(false);
            DDD1.setVisible(false);
            tel1.setVisible(false);
            stxddd.setVisible(false);
            stxnum.setVisible(false);
            stxtipo.setVisible(false);
            tipotel1.setVisible(false);
            DDD2.setVisible(false);
            tel2.setVisible(false);
            stxddd1.setVisible(false);
            stxnum1.setVisible(false);
            stxtipo1.setVisible(false);
            tipotel2.setVisible(false);
            btn_tel.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (validaresult2 == 2) {
            addtel.setVisible(true);
            DDD1.setVisible(true);
            tel1.setVisible(true);
            stxddd.setVisible(true);
            stxnum.setVisible(true);
            stxtipo.setVisible(true);
            tipotel1.setVisible(true);
            btn_tel.setVisible(true);
            DDD2.setVisible(false);
            tel2.setVisible(false);
            stxddd.setVisible(false);
            stxnum.setVisible(false);
            stxtipo.setVisible(false);
            tipotel2.setVisible(false);


        }

        String cpf1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.cpf");

        String nome1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.nome");
        info("nome " + nome1);

        String profissao1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.profissao");
        info("profissao " + profissao1);

        String email1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.email");
        info(email1);
        String indicado1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.indicado");
        info(indicado1);
        String rua = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("endereco_paciente.logradouro");
        info(rua);
        String bairro1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("endereco_paciente.bairro");
        info(bairro1);

        String cidade1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("endereco_paciente.cidade");
        info(cidade1);
        String cep1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("endereco_paciente.cep");
        info(cep1);

        String complemento1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("endereco_paciente.complemento");
        info(complemento1);
        Float num1 = (Float) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("endereco_paciente.numero");
        info("" + num1);
        String observacoes1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.observacoes");
        info(observacoes1);
        Date datanasc = (Date) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.nascimento");
        info("" + datanasc);
        String sexo1 = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.sexo");
        info(sexo1);
        String civil = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.estado_civil");
        info(civil);
        String indica = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("paciente.tipo_indicado");
        info(indica);
        cpf.setText(cpf1);
        nome2.setText(nome1);
        profissao.setText(profissao1);
        email.setText(email1);
        indicado.setText(indicado1);
        // indica2.setText(indica);
        lougradouro.setText(rua);
        bairro.setText(bairro1);
        cidade.setText(cidade1);
        complement.setText(complemento1);
        numero.setText(num1);
        data_nasc.setText(datanasc);
        observacoes.setText(observacoes1);

        cep.setText(cep1);

        txtsexo.setText(sexo1);
        txtestado.setText(civil);




    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        error("erro no list" + ex);
    }
```

Comment: Edita a pergunta e adiciona essa parte do codigo

Comment: Qual parte do código? Desculpa sou meio novato neste formatado do SOpt

Comment: Sem problemas e Bem vindo :), eu tambem nao percebo muito de web, mas essa parte de onde falas "quando busco outro cliente" tentar publicar essa parte do codigo

Comment: Adicionei o código :)

Comment: pufff nao te consigo ajudar...

Comment: A ausência da tua resposta indicaria implicitamente que não consegues ajudar de momento @jsantos1991.

Comment: Eu também não consigo ajudar, mas sempre que eu tenho algum erro misterioso eu sempre sigo o lema: "o erro está sempre em algo que **eu** escrevi"... No seu *stack trace*, o único código que não é do próprio Java é o `at yagaonline.medico.prontuario.listbox1_processValueChange(prontuario.java:3658)`, então eu começaria a procurar por aí.

Comment: @EugenioMichetti,dava para postar a parte do código da página onde passas como argumento `endereco_paciente.logradouro`? Pelo que vejo deve estar entre as linhas 810 a 820 do `prontuario.jsp`.

Comment: @ColdHack tens toda a razão mas visto que pedi para por código porque queria tentar ajudar, queria que o outro user soubesse que pelo menos tentei e não pedi por pedir, e alem disso (acho eu) dá um UP a pergunta e assim pode ser vista por mais alguém que saiba responder... Contudo tens razão é um comentário desnecessário...

Comment: @jsantos1991 esse "UP" só ocorre quando a pergunta ou uma das respostas é editada, não quando alguém comenta... :( No mais, acho válidas suas razões.

Comment: @mgibsonbr sim já reparei nisso, estava enganado...

Comment: @ColdHack segue a parte onde eu pega o logradouro. String rua = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("endereco_paciente.logradouro");

Comment: Era suposto editares a tua questão e colocar a porção do código da página(acredito que estas a utilizar `jsf`/`jsp`). Por outra, o método `pacienteDataProvider2.getValue` recebe como argumento uma `String` ou um `logradouro`?

Comment: Sim isto mesmo uso jsf/jsp. Recebe um logradouro, no banco de dados o campo logradouro é do tipo varchar(50). Geralmente quando eu busco a primeira vez o cliente não acontece nenhum problema, mas se eu buscar outro cliente recebo este erro, os 2 clientes possuem os "mesmos" dados.

Comment: Observei que esta exceção surge em varias linhas no teu código, ou seja, em várias partes executas métodos que estão a receber argumentos ilegais ou inadequados. Porquê usar `String rua = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue("endereco_paciente.logradouro");` em vez de `String rua = (String) pacienteDataProvider2.getValue(endereco_paciente.logradouro);`. Se `logradouro` no banco de dados é um `varchar(50)` então, creio, que esta a ser mapeado como um objecto do tipo `String`, certo?

Comment: Mas no caso eu tirando a " " não reconhece, creio eu que seja porque eu não tenho os métodos getters & setters. Este projeto é da empresa onde trabalho, como eles começaram assim tive que continuar assim.

Comment: PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO, o meu listbox estava com 2 ações no onChange, onde acabava gerando conflito de informações. Obrigado a atenção de todos. Obs: tem que colocar algo relacionado a "resolvido" ?

Comment: Seria interessante você colocar esse comentário lá como resposta, parece algo bobo mas pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta do Autor do Post:

**PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO, o meu listbox estava com 2 ações no onChange, onde acabava gerando conflito de informações**

Comment: Ascension, nestes casos que a gente só copia e cola um comentário do autor, a etiqueta é marcar a resposta como "wiki", assim vc não recebe pontos (nem perde), e que não são realmente seus, quando votarem na resposta. Não sei se vc ainda pode [edit] e fazer isso ou tem que sinalizar pros moderadores.

Comment: E lá na pergunta não devia ter colado a solução, reverti sua edição. O correto é publicar esta resposta mesmo.

Comment: Falha minha, @brasofilo, essa parte eu não sabia sobre etiquetar. Eu não tive tempo de ler os termos de uso do StackOverflow. E, tranquilo, sobre a edição!

Comment: Bom, neste caso, me refiro à [*Netiqueta*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiqueta) :) E sem problemas porque acho que isso não tá escrito na [help], já é mais uma coisa do [meta]. Saudações!